# unittest.mock: Set custom attribute (variable) on specced mock object

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I am trying to `mock` an existing object from another library's class for unit tests with `pytest`.
However, the attributes (not methods) from the other library are mostly set during runtime.

#### What I want to achieve

- Get all the benefits of mocking the object with `spec`
- Set the (nested) attributes (not methods) needed for my unittests to simulate as if they were set during object creation

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock
from otherlib import ClassName

def test_stuff():
    mock_object = Mock(spec=ClassName)
    mock_object.data.outward.key = 12345

    assert mock_object.data.outward.key == 12345  # AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'data'
```

#### I made these attempts in code changes but with no success

```py
...
def test_stuff():
    mock_object = Mock(spec=ClassName, **{'data.outward.key': 12345})

    assert mock_object.data.outward.key == 12345
```

```py
...
def test_stuff():
    mock_object = Mock(spec=ClassName)
    attrs = {'data.outward.key': 12345}
    mock_object.configure_mock(**attrs)

    assert mock_object.data.outward.key == 12345
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best I came up with is using another `Mock object` to use when setting the `main mock object's` attributes. It works, but I guess there is a better solution for this...?

```
from unittest.mock import Mock
from otherlib import ClassName

def test_stuff():
    mock_data = Mock(spec=["outward"], key=12345)
    mock_object = Mock(spec=ClassName, data=mock_data)
    mock_object.data.outward.key = 12345

    assert mock_object.data.outward.key == 12345  # tests.py::test_stuff PASSED [100%]
```